# WebRTC : Is it possible to have direct connection between a peer behind a normal NAT and other peer behind a symmetric NAT with STUN?

Tags: webrtc, nat, stun, turn

I have implemented WebRTC and things work well, but there is something I am not sure I understand. From my reading, I thought that when a peer is behind a symmetric NAT, a TURN server is mandatory.

I have tested this situation :

1. peerA is behind a normal NAT (confirmed via https://tomchen.github.io/symmetric-nat-test/)
2. peerB is behind a symmetric NAT. (confirmed via https://tomchen.github.io/symmetric-nat-test/)
3. The peer connection instance is only using a STUN server

WebRTC direct connection between peerA and peerB is working!

So, my question : Is it possible to have direct connection between a peer behind a normal NAT and other peer behind a symmetric NAT with STUN?

My test tells me yes but :

1. Can I trust the result of (https://tomchen.github.io/symmetric-nat-test/).  Maybe the information is incorrect?

Thank you

Comment: Symmetric NAT is the old classification. The new definition is called "address and port dependent mapping".  Run `stunclient --mode behavior your.stun.server.address` behind both peer A and peer B and tell me the results.  You can get the stunclient app for all platforms at www.stunprotocol.org

Comment: @selbie Both peerA and peerB returns `Binding test: success
Local address: 123.123.123.123:59413
Mapped address: 456.456.456.456:59413
Behavior test: fail`

Comment: If the behavior test fails, it means your STUN server only has 1 ip address.  You can't infer NAT behavior as reliably with only 1 ip address.  Run `stunclient --mode behavior stunserver.stunprotocol.org` to see the NAT behavior results against a 2-ip STUN service.

Comment: Also, 456.456.456.456 is not a valid IP address. I assume that's a typo when you obfuscated it? Otherwise, there's an even worse bug lurking.

Comment: @selbie Yes, I changed the IP address, 456 doesn't exist I know.  You second command returns this : 
`Binding test: success
Local address: 192.168.230.138:63123
Mapped address: 123.123.123.123:63123
Behavior test: success
Nat behavior: Endpoint Independent Mapping`

Comment: Endpoint Independent Mapping basically mean, "normal nat" and "not symmetric nat".  What that means is that with the same port contacting two different IP addresses gets the same port mapping. The web based NAT detection tools are slightly flawed because it attempts to contact 2 different IP addresses, but its not guranteed to use the same local port. WebRTC client code doesn't get to pick the local port. This behavior might be different between browsers. Try comparing between Chrome, Edge, and Firefox.

Comment: I did do a wireshark capture with Edge (Chromium version) and it does indeed use the same local port for both STUN servers. Interesting. The wireshark trace would be a sure-fire way of knowing what's going on on your end.